# Angular MatStepper fails to recognize cached values from two str arrays (but successfully recognizes values from another str array)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, caching, angular-material

I have a `MatStepper` that's used to navigate to the next page of a signup flow. I also have a method that loads values from a cache if it's available, and if so then the `MatStepper` skips to Page 2. After that, a future method pre-fills the form will those cached values.

The scenario where `cachedSports` are retrieved causes the `MatStepper` to *work* and skip to Page 2, but when I try to pre-fill with `cachedPets` or `cachedAnimals` the `MatStepper` fails and gives me the following error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'next')`

There aren't a lot of differences between `cachedSports` and the two failing scenarios, so I don't know what the culprit is. All three are arrays of strings and the values from their caches are coming in successfully.

---

```js
    // Cached values are retrieved from another file, memory-cache.service.ts
    loadFromCache(): void {
        const cachedPets: string[] = this.cacheService.get<string[]>(MemoryCacheService.WellKnownKeys.pets) ?? [];
        const cachedSports: string[] = this.cacheService.get<string[]>(MemoryCacheService.WellKnownKeys.sports) ?? [];
        const cachedAnimalNames: string[] = this.cacheService.get<string[]>(MemoryCacheService.WellKnownKeys.animals) ?? [];

        // Note that cachedPets and cachedAnimalNames share ('targetEveryAnimal')
        if (cachedPets.length > 0) {
          this.targetingFormGroup.get('targetEveryAnimal').setValue('Specific'); 
          this.targetPetChange({ value: 'Specific' }, cachedPets);
        } else if (cachedSports.length > 0) {
          this.targetingFormGroup.get('targetEverySport').setValue('Specific');
          this.targetSportChange({ value: 'Specific' }, cachedSports);
        } else if (cachedAnimalNames.length > 0) {
          this.targetingFormGroup.get('targetEveryAnimal').setValue('Specific');
          this.targetAnimalChange({ value: 'Specific' }, cachedAnimalNames);
        } 

        // The values correctly come through:
        console.log('cachedPets: ', cachedPets); // ["Cat"]
        console.log('cachedSports: ', cachedSports); // ["Tennis"]
        console.log('cachedAnimalNames: ', cachedAnimalNames); // ["Chinchilla"]

        this.goForward();
        this.location.replaceState('filters/setup/create/page2');
        this.skipPageOne = true;

        this.cacheService.remove(MemoryCacheService.WellKnownKeys.pets);
        this.cacheService.remove(MemoryCacheService.WellKnownKeys.sports);
        this.cacheService.remove(MemoryCacheService.WellKnownKeys.animals);

    }

  goForward(){
    this.myStepper.next();
    // Defined as: @ViewChild('stepper') private myStepper: MatStepper;
  }
```

---

#### This is where the cached values are actually added into the form

```js
// Same file as the above code

validateFormTargeting() {

  const sports = (spt === 'Specific') ? this.targetingFormGroup.get('sports').value : [];
  console.log('tfg-sports: ', this.targetingFormGroup.get('sports').value) // ["Tennis"]
  console.log('sports: ', sports) // ["Tennis"]

  let pets;
  let animalNames;

  if (animt === 'Specific') {
    // pets = this.tarFormGroup.get // etc
    animalNames = this.targetingFormGroup.get('animalNames') ? this.targetingFormGroup.get('animalNames').value : [];
    
    // The console messages (therefore this code block) is not reached because of the "Cannot read properties of undefined" error
    console.log('tfg-animalNames: ', this.targetingFormGroup.get('animalNames').value)
    console.log('animalNames: ', animalNames)
  }
}
```

---

#### Verbose err message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'next')
    at AppModalFormCreateComponent.goForward (myForm.component.ts:371:20)
    at AppModalFormCreateComponent.loadFromCache (myForm.component.ts:357:10)
    at AppModalFormCreateComponent.ngOnInit (myForm.component.ts:227:10)
```

Comment: It's the `ViewChild` not being defined/set when `goForward` is called. If the template is being updated then it's probably a timing issue. For testing purposes wrap the code in `goForward` in a `setTimeout`

Comment: @Drenai I wrapped the `goForward` in `setTimeout` and can confirm that the form is now skipping to Page 2. If you post your comment as an answer then I'll mark it as correct. --- PS - The original iteration of the code (prior to these changes) was only caching `cachedPets`, so perhaps caching other things helped fuel the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `ViewChild` not being defined/set when `goForward` is called.

If the template is being updated then it's probably a timing issue. For testing purposes you can wrap the code in `goForward` in a `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your code only run after ngAfterViewInit as it could be the case where you are trying to access and element before de view is rederend, resulting in a undefined property for the viewchild queried on the view.

NOTE: ngAfterViewInit may not be the best lifecycle option, so please choose from the list what ever is better for you.
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks